# How many ways are there to select 3 numbers from the set {1,2,3...99} so that the sum is even?

Tags: combinatorics

I tried this approach , the only way we can make an even sum is two odd and one even or $3$ even. So the answer is $${49\choose 3} + {50\choose2}\cdot{49\choose1}.$$
Is this correct? Is there any other way we can think of it?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: Do you have to choose distinct numbers? That might be a possible catch.

Comment: yes , I have to choose distinct numbers ..

Comment: @TamimAdDari: Looks correct then, as John Habert remarked.

Comment: Yes, the answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also focus on the remainder of the numbers $\mod 2$. Then the list of the numbers $\{1,2,3, ... ,99\}$ would turn into $\{1,0,1,0, ... ,1\}$, with $50$ ones and $49$ zeros. For the sum of $3$ numbers to be  $\equiv 0 \mod 2$ the only options are:

- $2$ ones and $1$ zero.  Here there are ${50\choose2}\cdot{49\choose1}$ ways.
- $3$ zeros.  Here there are ${49\choose 3}$ ways.

So the total number of ways is 
$$
{50\choose2}\cdot{49\choose1} + {49\choose 3} = 49^2 \cdot 25 + 49 \cdot 47 \cdot 8 = 49 \cdot 1601.
$$

It's quite similar reasoning, but this method it's easier to use when you're dealing with greater numbers e.g "The sum of $3$ numbers $\mod 37 \equiv 0$".

Comment: Hi @Foga, I've cleaned up your post a bit.  You can use `\mod` ($\mod n$) or `\pmod` ($\pmod n$) for modulo.  In math mode, `\{` and `\}` give you curly braces.  I've also changed some of the wording to be clearer.  Regards

Comment: thanks! actually I'm not so good at $MathJax$...I've to learn a bit about it... ;)

Answer (score 1):

yes it is correct as i see , you are a good one