# Choosing three distinct numbers giving even sum.

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we choose three distinct numbers from the set $\{1,2,...,99\}$ so that their sum is even?

I found a solution in [this StackExchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716862/how-many-ways-are-there-to-select-3-numbers-from-the-set-1-2-3-99-so-that-th) .

My question is:

When working with the case with two odd numbers and one even number, I first use the principle of counting to find all sequences containing two odd numbers and one even number as $50\times49\times49$. Then I divide by $3!$ as different permutations of the sequence don't count. I get a fractional value. Instead, if I divide by $2!$, i.e., only stripping away the arrangements of the two odd numbers (not all three digits!), I get the right answer.

I have some difficulties understanding this problem:

1. $\binom{50}{2}\times\binom{49}{1}$ implies we are considering  arrangements of 2-subsets of the set of odd numbers and 1-subsets of the set of even numbers. I don't understand why we don't divide this by $2!$ to discount the permutations of these two subsets.
2. Why is dividing by $3!$ incorrect?

Comment: $\binom{50}{2}\times\binom{49}{1}$ counts only odd-odd-even, not permutations such as odd-even-odd or even-odd-odd, because you are choosing two odd numbers before choosing the even number.

Comment: If we choose two odd numbers and then an even number, then wouldn't $\binom{50}{2}\times\binom{49}{1}$ count odd-odd-even as well as even-odd-odd which would require dividing by 2. I think I understand why odd-even-odd would not be counted, I think it is because we are choosing a subset of odd numbers, not odd numbers as distinct objects. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it often helps to think of *sample* objects which I am counting.

One of your confusions seems to be what $a \times b$ means in a counting formula.  I like to think of it as choosing among $a$ options first, and then, choosing among $b$ options, in that order (if order matters).  A typical object being chosen is a $2$-vector $(A,B)$, where $A$ is one of the $a$ options and $B$ is one of the $b$ options.  In particular a typical object is *not*  a $2$-set $\{A, B\}$.

- For ${50 \choose 2} \times {49 \choose 1}$, a typical object is a $2$-vector $(A,B)$ where $A$ is a $2$-subset of odd numbers and $B$ is a $1$-subset of even number.  Every desired $3$-subset of $2$ odd numbers and $1$ even number can be written in this way in exactly one way.  So no need to divide.  E.g. $\{23, 4, 17\} = (\{23, 17\}, \{4\})$.

  - In particular ${50 \choose 2} \times {49 \choose 1}$ does not count $2$odd-even "as well as" even-$2$odd.  For that you would need ${50 \choose 2} \times {49 \choose 1} +  {49 \choose 1} \times {50 \choose 2}$... and then of course you need to divide by $2!$.
- For $50 \times 49 \times 49$, first decide which $49$ means what.  The fact that they are the same number is just a coincidence.  Lets say you arrived at that formula thinking the first $49$ is choosing the second odd number, i.e. you're choosing odd-odd-even.  So then a typical object is a $3$-vector $(A,B,C)$ where $A, B$ are distinct odd numbers and $C$ is even.  Any desired $3$-subset can be written in this $3$-vector form in $2$ ways, e.g. $\{23, 4, 17\} = (23,17,4)$ or $(17,23,4)$, and crucially, $(23,17,4) \neq (17,23,4)$, so you divide by $2!$.

  - If you decide the first $49$ means the even number, i.e. you're choosing odd-even-odd, it's the same deal.  But again, $50 \times 49 \times 49$ does not include odd-odd-even "as well as" odd-even-odd.  For that you would need $50 \times 49 \times 49 + 50 \times 49 \times 49$.  And if you include even-odd-odd you would need $50 \times 49 \times 49 + 50 \times 49 \times 49 + 49 \times 50 \times 49$... and then you would truly need to divide by $3!$.

Comment: I think I understand now. I was confusing this with counting permutations. More generally, when we count permutations, we are picking elements from only ONE SET, so if we have a set and we pick an element from it first, and then another second, the second element is also counted in the possibilities for the first. Thus, both permutations are available. In this case however, we have two different sets. Thus, assuming we pick one set first, the first spot is reserved for an element in the first set. In this, an element from the second set is not counted in the first position. Am I correct?

Comment: basically yes.  :)